# script to click a link at a certain time

Tags: webbrowser-control, httprequest

I am interested in writing a script that goes to a website and clicks a link at a certain time. How do I go about doing something like this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, just really needed a place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You should use selenium http://seleniumhq.org/
You can control it using anyone of the language you specified in the tags.

You can start to browse from 
http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/

Answer (score 2):

"clicking a link" could have two meanings:

Actually clicking the link in a browser, or just doing an HTTP GET that would result from it. This could be as simple as software that runs on your desktop and simulates a click at a certain point, to something as complicated as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for automation of website interactions.

If you just need to do the GET request that clicking the link would do, anything would do.  Unix systems typically include `wget` and `curl`, which take a url to request. Or if you want to process the data, you can do this in most programming languages. For example, in python you could do `urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com')` and then do whatever you want with the data. Perl has an equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with cURL?

Comment: +1 or wget, or something set to run on cron (*nix) or scheduled task (windows)